# A famous literacy test question

Tags: word, visual

This question may be well known to some, but I still think it is interesting:

[image]

It comes from the 1964 Louisiana literacy test which you had to take to be eligible to vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are there people who *don't* know this? :)

> Paris in the **the** spring
>  The word 'the' is repeated; people often miss it, as the way we read tends to gloss over unimportant words.

The alternative answer, for the pedantic grammarians, is

> **what you read in the triangle below.**

but that assumes you insist on ignoring the clear surface intent of the question.  Both alternatives, honestly, qualify as "an annoying way to trick people".  The alternative just amps it up to 11.

Comment: There is more than one possible answer. Can you work out the other one?

Comment: Got it!  And I agree with your comment too. Sadly I believe this was indeed the original intention.

Answer (score 2):

The illusion is that when you first read it you see

> Paris in the spring

But it actually reads

> Paris in the **the** spring - two 'the's

Comment: Ninja'd ya by 3 seconds. :)

Comment: @Rubio damn it!

Comment: I am not sure this is right answer now I think about it.

Comment: @Lembik well I wrote what was in the triangle

Comment: Yes but you are not thinking about it as an annoying way to trick people, which was how it was designed. The comma seems to be the key.

Comment: @Lembik look it up online. This is the answer

Comment: Is there a definitive answer online? I also looked it up and there is an alternative.